# SwiftUI ScrollView scrolls when items added

Tags: swiftui

In several places in my app, I implement a paged loading scheme using a `ScrollView` and a `LazyVStack`, with an `ProgressView` after the loaded items. The `ProgressView` is only shown if the model has more items to load, and on appear of the `ProgressView`, loading of the next page is triggered.

The new items get appended to the list in the model, and they get rendered, pushing the `ProgressView` off the bottom of the screen. When the user scrolls up, the `ProgressView` reappears, and triggers loading of the next page.

For some reason, in one list where I’m using a `LazyVGrid` inside a `LazyVStack`, when the next page loads, the entire view scrolls such that the bottom of the stack is still displayed, causing the `ProgressView` to sit there spinning. It’s as if the `ScrollView` is pinning the scroll to the bottom of its content, and I can’t figure out why.

The view looks like this:

```swift
ScrollView
{
    LazyVStack
    {
        LazyVGrid(columns: self.columns, spacing: 20.0)
        {
            if let products = self.collection.products,
                products.count > 0
            {
                ForEach(products)
                { inProduct in
                    NavigationLink(destination: ProductDetailsContainerView(searchResult: WNProductSearchResult(product: inProduct)))
                    {
                        ProductListingCell(imageURL: inProduct.imageURL,
                                            title: inProduct.name,
                                            listingCount: inProduct.availableCount,
                                            price: inProduct.marketPrice)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        if let products = self.collection.products,
            products.count == 0
        {
            self.emptyDisplay
        }
        
        //  Progress loader triggers loading…
        
        if self.collection.hasMore
        {
            HStack
            {
                Spacer()
                ProgressView()
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.top, 40)
            .onAppear { self.collection.load(next: 20) }
        }
    }
    .padding(20)
}
```

Even more bafflingly, this only occurs after the second page loads. The first page loads as expected; then you scroll to the bottom, the `ProgressView` is revealed, the second page loads, and the items fill in without moving the scroll position. If you then scroll up again, the `ProgressView` is revealed, the third page loads, and the items fill in, but the scroll view is repositioned such that you’re looking at the new bottom of the list.

Hopefully you can see the behavior:

[image: Animated GIF of loading & scrolling behavior]

Comment: Can you include a [mre]? What you've included won't compile because of missing types/code.

Comment: Not really, no. There's a substantial amount of networking code behind this, not to mention authentication.

Comment: Sure, but couldn't that be easily mocked into an example format the loads bogus data or content?

Comment: Not easily, no.

Comment: Unfortunately, then it is unlikely to be easily debugged and answered here.